# How to call a $rootScope variable with bracket notation on a AngularJs view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this html in my view

```
<div ng-repeat="newsItem in Items" >
    <div style="background: url({{::newsItem.teaser) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>
```

in the `$rootScope` I have an object that contains generated local URLs in this way:

- $rootScope.images.someName
- $rootScope.images.someNameX
- $rootScope.images.someName3

My variables `newsItem.teaser` contains the names someName, someNameX, someName3. How can I use $root['someName'] in my view? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `ngStyle` in this way

```
<div ng-style="{'background': 'url({{$root.images[newsItem.teaser]}}) no-repeat center center', 'background-size': cover}"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to specify $rootScope in html. You can use it the same way as you use $scope variables

```
<h1>{{newsItem.teaser.someName}}</h1>
```

Comment: When I just left it in that way I become this `.. url(someName) no-repeat...` it just use the text instead of look for the `$rootscope` item

Comment: @distante i dont get it

Comment: @Sabeetharan it just renders the name as a string.